# Django-like date based archive with Flask and SqlAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask

I am revisiting python and web development. i used Django in the past but it's been a while. Flask + SqlAlchemy is all new to me but I like the control it gives me.

To start off; the code below works like a charm on my dev server. Still I have the feeling that it is not as small and efficient as it could be. I was wondering if anyone has built a similar solution. For now I am trying to find a way to use a single query and format the keyword arguments into it. Further more I think it might me useful to build a class around the function in order to make it more reuse-able.

Here is the function to construct a query based on date:

```
def live_post_filter(year=None, month=None, day=None):
    """ Query to filter only published Posts exluding drafts 
    Takes additional arguments to filter by year, month and day
    """
    live = Post.query.filter(Post.status == Post.LIVE_STATUS).order_by(Post.pub_date.desc())

    if year and month and day:
        queryset = live.filter(extract('year', Post.pub_date) == year,
                           extract('month', Post.pub_date) == month,
                           extract('day', Post.pub_date) == day).all()
    elif year and month:
        queryset = live.filter(extract('year', Post.pub_date) == year,
                           extract('month', Post.pub_date) == month).all()
    elif year:
        queryset = live.filter(extract('year', Post.pub_date) == year).all()
    else:
        queryset = live.all()

    return queryset
```

Here is how I call above function from a view:

```
@mod.route('/api/get_posts/', methods = ['GET'])
@mod.route('/api/get_posts/<year>/<month>/<day>/', methods = ['GET'])
@mod.route('/api/get_posts/<year>/<month>/', methods = ['GET'])
@mod.route('/api/get_posts/<year>/', methods = ['GET'])
def get_posts(year=None, month=None, day=None):
    posts = live_post_filter(year=year, month=month, day=day)
    postlist = []
    if request.method == 'GET':
    # do stuff
```

As stated above, all of this feels quite clunky, any advise would me much appreciated.

Comment: Some tips: You only need one `route` call as you can use the `defaults` keyword argument to provide defaults when nothing is provided. `GET` is the default method. You can limit your routes to valid values with converts.  So all of your route decorators can be replaced with this *one*:  `@mod.route('/api/get_posts/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>', defaults={'year': None, 'month': None, 'day': None})`

Comment: If I use just the single decorator only the endpoint works, for some reason. Have not found out why.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `extract` to filter by date components seems odd to me. I would instead create an auxiliary function that returns a range of dates from your `year`, `month` and `day` arguments:

```
def get_date_range(year=None, month=None, day=None):
    from_date = None
    to_date = None
    if year and month and day:
        from_date = datetime(year, month, day)
        to_date = from_date
    elif year and month:
        from_date = datetime(year, month, 1)
        month += 1
        if month > 12:
            month = 1
            year += 1
        to_date = datetime(year, month, 1)
    elif year:
        from_date = datetime(year, 1, 1)
        to_date = datetime(year + 1, 1, 1)
    return from_date, to_date
```

And then the query function becomes much simpler:

```
def live_post_filter(year=None, month=None, day=None):
    """ Query to filter only published Posts exluding drafts 
    Takes additional arguments to filter by year, month and day
    """
    live = Post.query.filter(Post.status == Post.LIVE_STATUS).order_by(Post.pub_date.desc())
    from_date, to_date = get_date_range(year, month, day)
    if from_date and to_date:
        live = live.filter(Post.pub_date >= from_date, Post.pub_date < to_date)
    return live.all()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. Might update my answer with a result later.